# Can't make a script change text at a certain time in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

I created a script to change the text but the text changes by seconds and I need the text to change at a certain time and not by seconds!

At the end of the Text, the function should be activated green flash!

After the green flash, all players must teleport to the place where the teleport is!

After all the players have teleported, an Update should appear!

```lua
Label=script.Parent.Label 
Interval=5 -- Time Between Change 
 
while true do 
    Label.Text="2 DAYS" -- The 1st Text Shown 
    wait(20) 
    Label.Text="1 DAY" 
    wait(20) 
    break 
end
```

Comment: Isn't Roblox LUA, not Javascript?

Comment: Please try to keep your questions more [focused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417486#417486) and use appropriate language tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.